# Using local html file with webview in expo app

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, webview, expo

I am developing react native application with **expo**. I want to reuse some of my react codes inside it. However, even i am able to load html file in **webview**, i get error about used external local files in html. It seems it cannot load local javascript files.

**React Native code;**

```
<WebView
   style={styles.webview}
   originWhitelist={['*']}
   allowFileAccess={true}
   baseURL='../../web/'
   source={require('../../web/index.html')}
   domStorageEnabled={true}
   allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
   allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
   mixedContentMode='always'
/>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title">Hello! this is a test component</div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('file is fully loaded');
};
```

**index.css**

```
.title {
    background-color: red;
    color: white
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

I think, a good solution could be moving the folder into **assets** folder of android and **resources** folder for ios but i did not find any solution for moving folders(not files).